# destructivechanges.xml build error - -Error: Not in package.xml

Tags: destructivechanges.xml, ant-script

I set up and ran destructiveChanges.xml through the ANT tool to delete custom fields from the Activity object in the sandbox.

I am getting an error -

> Error: Not in package.xml

build file:

```
<project name="Sample usage of Salesforce Ant tasks" default="test" basedir="." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">

    <!--<property file="build.properties"/>-->
    <property environment="env"/>

     <property name="my.pkgName" value="Activity Custom Fields" />

    <!-- Setting default value for username, password and session id properties to empty string 
         so unset values are treated as empty. Without this, ant expressions such as ${sf.username}
         will be treated literally.
    -->
    <condition property="sf.username" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.username"/> </not> </condition>
    <condition property="sf.password" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.password"/> </not> </condition>
    <condition property="sf.sessionId" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.sessionId"/> </not> </condition>

    <taskdef resource="com/salesforce/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:com.salesforce">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="ant-salesforce.jar"/>            
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

     <target name="retrievePkg">
      <mkdir dir="${my.pkgName}"/>

      <sf:retrieve username="my username" password="pw and security token" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="https://test.salesforce.com" maxPoll="200" retrieveTarget="${my.pkgName}"  packageNames="${my.pkgName}" />
    </target>
    <!-- Shows deploying code & running tests for code in directory -->
    <target name="deployScript">

      <sf:deploy 
            checkOnly="false"
            username="my username" 
            password="pw and security token" 
            serverurl="https://test.salesforce.com" 
            maxPoll="10000" 
            pollWaitMillis="1000" 
            deployRoot="C:\\Salesforce\\Activity Custom Fields"
            testLevel="NoTestRun"
            ignoreWarnings="true">
      </sf:deploy>
    </target>   
  </project>
```

destructiveChanges.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">

<fullName>Activity Custom Fields</fullName>

<description>Custom fields on the activity object for deletion.</description>


-<types>

<members>Activity.Alert_Users__c</members>

<members>Activity.Attendance__c</members>

<members>Activity.CCR_Data__c</members>

<members>Activity.CCR_Functionality__c</members>

<members>Activity.CCR_Messaging__c</members>

<members>Activity.CCR_Resource_Allocation__c</members>

<members>Activity.CCR_Training__c</members>

<members>Activity.Campaign_Design_Profile_Name__c</members>

<members>Activity.Campaign_Event__c</members>

<members>Activity.Client_Request_Goal__c</members>

<members>Activity.Company_List__c</members>

<members>Activity.Company_Suppression_List__c</members>

<members>Activity.Contact_Information__c</members>

<members>Activity.Contact_List__c</members>

<members>Activity.Contact_Suppression_List__c</members>

<members>Activity.DC_Agent__c</members>

<members>Activity.D_B_PO_Number__c</members>

<members>Activity.Data_Team_Comments__c</members>

<members>Activity.Date_Delivered__c</members>

<members>Activity.Date_Sent_to_Partner__c</members>

<members>Activity.Deadline_Not_Met_Reason__c</members>

<members>Activity.Delivery_Channel__c</members>

<members>Activity.ETA_Back_to_Sales__c</members>

<members>Activity.Employee_Count__c</members>

<members>Activity.Industry__c</members>

<members>Activity.Install_Base__c</members>

<members>Activity.Key_Resources__c</members>

<members>Activity.Location_Type__c</members>

<members>Activity.Master_CDP_Number__c</members>

<members>Activity.New_ETA__c</members>

<members>Activity.No_Owner_Match__c</members>

<members>Activity.Notes__c</members>

<members>Activity.PO_Number__c</members>

<members>Activity.Partner_Contacts__c</members>

<members>Activity.Partner_Orgs__c</members>

<members>Activity.Partner__c</members>

<members>Activity.Product_Name__c</members>

<members>Activity.Production_Contacts__c</members>

<members>Activity.Production_Org__c</members>

<members>Activity.Reachforce_PO_number__c</members>

<members>Activity.Reason_Due_Date_Not_Met__c</members>

<members>Activity.Region__c</members>

<members>Activity.Reopen_Reason__c</members>

<members>Activity.Request_Status__c</members>

<members>Activity.Request_Type__c</members>

<members>Activity.Revised_Due_Date__c</members>

<members>Activity.Sales_Comments__c</members>

<members>Activity.Sales_Revenue__c</members>

<members>Activity.Social_123_PO_Number__c</members>

<members>Activity.Source_ID__c</members>

<members>Activity.Status_Notes__c</members>

<members>Activity.Target_Department__c</members>

<members>Activity.Target_Level__c</members>

<members>Activity.Type_of_Visit__c</members>

<members>Activity.Visit_Date_s__c</members>

<members>Activity.Zip_Code__c</members>

<members>Activity.Zip_Radius__c</members>

<name>CustomField</name>

</types>

<version>43.0</version>

</Package>
```

package.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <version>43.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: Would you please [edit] to include your `destructiveChanges.xml` and `package.xml` used for this job?

Comment: The `package.xml` in your destructive run should be empty.... (other than the version tag)

Comment: May try `sfdx force:source:delete`?

Comment: @BrianMiller I'm not familiar with that function or how/where to use it.

Comment: @SebastianKessel I have made the package.xml empty other than the version tag, but now the build fails on Error: Not in package.xml -- any ideas here? Is it my build file? Would it be helpful if I post my build script?

Comment: See the [source:delete](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm) documentation.  Example: `sfdx force:source:delete -m ApexClass:MyClassToDelete -u MySandboxOrg -w -r`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `package.xml` file is not [constructed correctly for a destructive deployment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy_deleting_files.htm?search_text=destructiveChanges):

> To deploy the destructive changes, you must also have a package.xml file that lists no components to deploy, includes the API version, and is in the same directory as destructiveChanges.xml

You should remove all of the component declarations from your `package.xml` and retry.

Rolling up from comments... When performing a destructive deployment, the *only* items in your ZIP package or payload should be the `package.xml` and `destructiveChanges.xml` files. If you're getting errors that say

> Error: Not in package.xml

that suggests that your payload is not being built correctly and actually contains metadata components that are not in your `package.xml` (which is empty). The Metadata API complains because it's getting the component metadata, but not a declaration of what to do with it (the package).

That is *not* what you want here, and you also don't want to do a deployment with `destructiveChangesPost.xml`, which does a regular deployment first and then performs a deletion.

Without seeing the details of your build scripts, we can't tell you what is getting built and why. If you just need to perform a destructive deployment, you can do so by creating a ZIP archive yourself with the two XML files you need and using Workbench to perform the operation directly, rather than going through Ant.

### Ant Script Details

Based on the Ant script you've shared, it appears that your Ant is configured only to perform a deployment of a specific folder, currently set to `deployRoot="C:\\Salesforce\\Activity Custom Fields"`. You'd want to set that parameter to point at a directory that *does not contain any metadata files*. It should contain only the `package.xml` and the `destructiveChanges.xml` files. If the directory contains metadata files, such as custom field information, you will receive an error stating that there are components not in `package.xml`.

Comment: I added the build script. I am not familiar with workbench and am a sf admin, not a developer (obviously). I learned this last year from a developer who had me run this as destructiveChangesPost. Since you don't recommend that, I am trying to learn the right way. I also read the ANT material in the developer site since you posted the link and I am not understanding what I'm doing wrong. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @LauraBabb I will expand on this answer tomorrow to try to address those issues.

Comment: Have you had an opportunity to look at this?

Comment: @LauraBabb I added a few more details/suggestions at the end

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for that "**Not in package.xml**" error is that you have the metadata folders in the same folder as the `package.xml` and `destructiveChanges.xml`.

**The two xml files need to be in a folder by themselves.**

Thanks @David Reed.  It was in your answer, but I wanted to emphasize it.